# Creating a Menu with c

Tags: c-preprocessor

I am trying to create a menu and my menu is listed a-d. I want the if statement to read a for first item in menu all the way to do but my program keeps crashing. How can I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

     char option[4];



     system("cls");

     printf("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++>>>ATHLETE DATA MANAGEMENT SYSTEM<<<++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++\n\n");
     printf("\t\t\t\t\ta\. Enter Athlete Data\n");
     printf("\t\t\t\t\tb\. Determine Distance to Reach World Record\n");
     printf("\t\t\t\t\tc\. Display Athlete Management Report\n");
     printf("\t\t\t\t\td\. Exit\n");


    printf("Type the corresponding letter (a-d) to access the menu. ");
    scanf("%d", &option);

    if(strcmp(option, "a")==0){
        printf("Welcome to Athlete Data Page\n");
    }
    else if(strcmp(option,"b")==0){
        printf("Determine Distance to Reach World Record\n");

    }else if(strcmp(option, "c")==0){
        printf("Athlete Management Report");

    }else if (strcmp(option, "d")==0){
        printf("Exit Menu");
            printf("Press Y for yes and N for no");
        }
        else{
            printf("Incorrect code entered.");
        }
           return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please describe *how* it crashes. Is there an error message? When does it crash? Just after startup? During compilation? After you have pressed some key?

Comment: The error is right after startup where it is saying that program has stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a C-style string variable (an array of characters) `char option[4];`, but reading it as a decimal integer using the `%d` in `scanf`. You would want the `%s` option to do that.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm